# Error acessing SQlite in Xamarin Forms through SQLite-Net-PCL

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net

I've been trying to follow a very simple tutorial for a xamarin forms app with db access and I've struggled here.

I'm using VS 2017 and Xamarin Forms with NET Standard.
Also, sqlite-net-pcl 1.4.118 which is the latest stable.

This is my MainActivity code (android)

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);


        string fileName = "books_db.sqlite";
        string fileLocation = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(fileLocation, fileName);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App(fullPath));
    }
```

This is my App.xaml (in the shared library)

```
    /// <summary>   Full pathname of the database file, sent through Android/iOS projects. </summary>
    public static string DB_PATH = string.Empty;

    public App(string DB_Path) 
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DB_PATH = DB_Path;

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }
```

This is my MainPage (in the shared library)

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        try
        {
            // >> This throws an exception <<
            using (SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH)) 
            {
                conn.CreateTable<Book>();

                var books = conn.Table<Book>().ToList();

                lviewBooks.ItemsSource = books;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Error", ex.GetType().ToString() + ex.Message, "OK");
        }
    }
```

Once it gets to the sqlite using statement an exception is thrown when debugging in my emulator (Android 4.4 API 19).

[image]

Comment: Set a breakpoint and see what the path is and whether or not you can access said path.

Comment: The path is in the screenshot, as it is stated in the exception message. How can I check in the emulator if I can access that specific path?

Comment: `adb shell` into the emulator and use `cd` commands to change to that directory :)

Comment: Found the "bug"... everything is fine, except my Path.Combine is not working as expected. It is not combining the filename at all, but I don't see anything wrong! If I manually set 'string fullPath = fileLocation + "/" + fileName;' then it's good...